# Как получить строку? (Python 3.8)

Tags: python, строки

Имеется несколько строк (6). Нужно их "Соединить" в одну строку, чтобы между строками был "Разделитель"(//).
Пример: строка1 = да; строка2 = нет; строка3 = почти; "мега строка" = да//нет//почти
Не интересует такой способ, как "строка1 + "//" + строка2 + "//" + строка3"
  Python 3.8

Comment: `"//".join((строка1: строка2, строка3))`.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
a = 'wert'
b = 'qaz'
c = 'rok'
abc = '{0} // {1} // {2} //'.format(a,b,c)
print(abc)
```